# Spritesheet help in pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, sprite, sprite-sheet

I am currently working on a game, trying to improve my beginner python skills. My game is functioning at its most basic level - I can't bring myself to move forward in its development until I can animate my sprite. It's given me the worst headache -- induced by hours of staring at other peoples code, copy and pasting to no avail, and watching countless youtube videos. For some reason, I just cant seem to understand the basic concept of how to strip images from a spritesheet. I've seen the pygame website for it, I just don't understand it. I was following along with kids can code, but his spritesheet had an 'xml'? file attached so he could just copy and paste the coordinates. My spritesheet is 192x192 pixels so I was trying to load/split images by coordinates separated by 48. For example - (0,0,48,0). I was assuming these variables were  x, y, previousSpriteEndingx, previousSpriteEndingy by his example, and also because that's just the only thing I could get to make sense. I grouped each sprite location into lists of corresponding direction - up, down, left, and right. (I didnt want to translate and flip my L/R, but now that I'm thinking about it, would this make my game faster? Since it wouldn't have to load 4 new images?)

I finally got it to actually run, but instead of showing my sprite, it's just a black box that increases in width as it moves, but looks like it's too large to be my sprite. So I know I did something wrong with the coordinates (The box disappears when I press down). If someone could give me a working example that I could copy and paste to run and dissect, explain it so that a beginner could easily understand, or (I saved the best for last) implement something into the code pasted below, I would be forever grateful. Last time I posted here I got great help, and I'm hoping to replicate those results. This is a link to my SpriteSheet
https://ibb.co/eZbd2G

```
import pygame

WIDTH = 1000
HEIGHT = 700
FPS = 60

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        width = 25
        height = 25
        image = pygame.image.load("CharacterSprite.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(image, (width, height))
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH / 2 - 480   #center of rectangle
        self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT - 5  #pixels up from the bottom
        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = 0
        self.walkingright = []
        self.walkingleft = []
        self.walkingup = []
        self.walkingdown = []
        self.direction = 'R'


    #Facing Down
    sprite_sheet = SpriteSheet('CharacterSprite.png')
    image = sprite_sheet.get_image(0,0,48,0)
    self.walkingdown.append(image) 
    image = sprite_sheet.get_image(48,0,96,0)
    self.walkingdown.append(image)
    image = sprite_sheet.get_image(96,0,144,0)
    self.walkingdown.append(image)
    image = sprite_sheet.get_image(144,0,192,0)
    self.walkingdown.append(image)


    #Facing Up
    image = sprite_sheet.get_image(192,144,48,144)
    self.walkingup.append(image) 
    image = sprite_sheet.get_image(48,144,96,144)
    self.walkingup.append(image)
    image = sprite_sheet.get_image(96,144,144,144)
    self.walkingup.append(image)
    image = sprite_sheet.get_image(144,144,192,144)
    self.walkingup.append(image)


    #Facing Right
    image = sprite_sheet.get_image(192,96,48,96)
    self.walkingright.append(image)
    image = sprite_sheet.get_image(48,96,96,96)
    self.walkingright.append(image)
    image = sprite_sheet.get_image(96,96,144,96)
    self.walkingright.append(image)
    image = sprite_sheet.get_image(144,96,192,96)
    self.walkingright.append(image)

    #FacingLeft
    image = sprite_sheet.get_image(192,48,48,48)
    self.walkingleft.append(image)
    image = sprite_sheet.get_image(48,48,96,48)
    self.walkingleft.append(image)
    image = sprite_sheet.get_image(96,48,144,48)
    self.walkingleft.append(image)
    image = sprite_sheet.get_image(144,48,192,48)
    self.walkingleft.append(image)


def update(self):
    pos = self.rect.x
    if self.direction == "R":
        frame = (pos // 30) % len(self.walkingright)
        self.image = self.walkingright[frame]
    if self.direction == "L":
        frame = (pos // 30) % len(self.walkingleft)
        self.image = self.walkingleft[frame]
    if self.direction == "U":
        frame = (pos // 30) % len(self.walkingup)
        self.image = self.walkingup[frame]
    if self.direction == "D":
        frame = (pos // 30) % len(self.walkingdown)
        self.image = self.walkingdown[frame]

    self.speedx = 0 #Need these to make sure
    self.speedy = 0 #Sprite stops moving on keyup
    keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        self.speedx = -5
        self.direction = 'L'
    if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        self.speedx = 5
        self.direction = 'R'
    if keystate[pygame.K_UP]:
        self.speedy = -5
        self.direction = 'U'
    if keystate[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        self.speedy = 5
        self.direction = 'D'
    self.rect.x += self.speedx
    self.rect.y += self.speedy

    #Set Walls for Width and Height
    if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
        self.rect.rect = WIDTH
    if self.rect.left < 0:
        self.rect.left = 0
    if self.rect.top < 0:
        self.rect.top = 0
    if self.rect.bottom > HEIGHT:
        self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT


class SpriteSheet(object):
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.sprite_sheet = pygame.image.load(file_name)
    def get_image(self, x, y, width, height):
        image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        image.blit(self.sprite_sheet, (0,0), (x, y, width, height))
        image.set_colorkey(BLUE)
        return image

def update(self):
    if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
        self.rect.right = WIDTH
    if self.rect.top < 0:
        self.rect.top = 0
    if self.rect.bottom > HEIGHT:
        self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT
    self.rect.x += self.speedx
    #kill if it goes off screen
    if self.rect.left > WIDTH:
        self.kill()  

#Loading Graphics
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)
projectiles = pygame.sprite.Group()

#Spawn x amount of mobs, add to all sprites and mobs
running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            player.shoot()

 #Update Game Loop           
all_sprites.update()
screen.fill(WHITE)
all_sprites.draw(screen)
pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I took out everything from my game and left just the barebones structure that anybody would be able to copy, paste, and run with just my spritesheet, in hopes that more people would participate in helping me ;p

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code. Currently code has wrong indentions and it can't be run.

Comment: I know but for some reason it wasn't properly formatting the entire length of my code... was really pissing me off so I just 4spaced everything that didn't auto format lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working version of your program (read the comments). The main problem was that you didn't pass the correct width and height (48) as the third and fourth arguments to `sprite_sheet.get_image`.

To load images with transparency you can call `convert_alpha()`:

```
self.sprite_sheet = pygame.image.load(file_name).convert_alpha()
```

And in the `update` method of the `Player` you also needed the y-coordinate for the vertical movement.

```
if self.direction == "U":
    frame = (pos_y // 30) % len(self.walkingup)
```

---

```
import pygame

WIDTH = 1000
HEIGHT = 700
FPS = 60

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        width = 25
        height = 25
        sheet = pygame.image.load('Character_Sprite.png').convert_alpha()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(sheet, (48, 48))
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH / 2 - 480   #center of rectangle
        self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT - 5  #pixels up from the bottom
        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = 0
        self.walkingright = []
        self.walkingleft = []
        self.walkingup = []
        self.walkingdown = []
        self.direction = 'R'

        sprite_sheet = SpriteSheet('Character_Sprite.png')
        #Facing Down
        # Start at x = 0. Pass 48 as the third and
        # fourth argument (width and height).
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(0,0,48,48)
        self.walkingdown.append(image) 
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(48,0,48,48)
        self.walkingdown.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(96,0,48,48)
        self.walkingdown.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(144,0,48,48)
        self.walkingdown.append(image)

        #Facing Up
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(0,144,48,48)
        self.walkingup.append(image) 
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(48,144,48,48)
        self.walkingup.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(96,144,48,48)
        self.walkingup.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(144,144,48,48)
        self.walkingup.append(image)

        #Facing Right
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(0,96,48,48)
        self.walkingright.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(48,96,48,48)
        self.walkingright.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(96,96,48,48)
        self.walkingright.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(144,96,48,48)
        self.walkingright.append(image)

        #Facing Left
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(0,48,48,48)
        self.walkingleft.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(48,48,48,48)
        self.walkingleft.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(96,48,48,48)
        self.walkingleft.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(144,48,48,48)
        self.walkingleft.append(image)

    def update(self):
        pos_x = self.rect.x
        # You also need the y position for the vertical movement.
        pos_y = self.rect.y
        if self.direction == "R":
            frame = (pos_x // 30) % len(self.walkingright)
            self.image = self.walkingright[frame]
        if self.direction == "L":
            frame = (pos_x // 30) % len(self.walkingleft)
            self.image = self.walkingleft[frame]
        if self.direction == "U":
            frame = (pos_y // 30) % len(self.walkingup)
            self.image = self.walkingup[frame]
        if self.direction == "D":
            frame = (pos_y // 30) % len(self.walkingdown)
            self.image = self.walkingdown[frame]

        self.speedx = 0 #Need these to make sure
        self.speedy = 0 #Sprite stops moving on keyup
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speedx = -5
            self.direction = 'L'
        if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speedx = 5
            self.direction = 'R'
        if keystate[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.speedy = -5
            self.direction = 'U'
        if keystate[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.speedy = 5
            self.direction = 'D'
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        self.rect.y += self.speedy

        #Set Walls for Width and Height
        if self.rect.right > WIDTH:
            self.rect.rect = WIDTH
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        if self.rect.top < 0:
            self.rect.top = 0
        if self.rect.bottom > HEIGHT:
            self.rect.bottom = HEIGHT


class SpriteSheet(object):
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        # You have to call `convert_alpha`, so that the background of
        # the surface is transparent.
        self.sprite_sheet = pygame.image.load(file_name).convert_alpha()

    def get_image(self, x, y, width, height):
        # Use a transparent surface as the base image (pass pygame.SRCALPHA).
        image = pygame.Surface([width, height], pygame.SRCALPHA)
        image.blit(self.sprite_sheet, (0,0), (x, y, width, height))
        return image


all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)

running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    all_sprites.update()
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

---

You can also shorten the sprite sheet cutting code with some for loops:

```
# Facing Up
for x in range(0, 144+1, 48):  # 144+1 because the `stop` is exclusive.
    self.walkingdown.append(sprite_sheet.get_image(x, 0, 48, 48))
# Facing Up
for x in range(0, 144+1, 48):
    self.walkingup.append(sprite_sheet.get_image(x, 144, 48, 48))
# Facing Right
for x in range(0, 144+1, 48):
    self.walkingright.append(sprite_sheet.get_image(x, 96, 48, 48))
# Facing Left
for x in range(0, 144+1, 48):
    self.walkingleft.append(sprite_sheet.get_image(x, 48, 48, 48))
```

---

Here's an even shorter way to cut the sheet. You can iterate over the image lists and enumerate them to get the y index and add a nested `for` loop for the x coord, and then use [`pygame.Surface.subsurface`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface) to cut out the subsurfaces. The `SpriteSheet` class wouldn't be needed anymore.

```
image_lists = (self.walkingdown, self.walkingleft, self.walkingright, self.walkingup)
for y, img_list in enumerate(image_lists):  # Enumerate to get the y-position.
    for x in range(4):
        # Multiply x and y by 48 to get the correct coords and use the
        # `subsurface` to cut the sheet into separate images.
        img_list.append(sheet.subsurface(x*48, y*48, 48, 48))
```

Comment: Dude.... You are the man. This is exactly what I needed, and I appreciate all the extra's, too. Taught me to fish.

Comment: One more suggestion: I'd probably change the animation code, because it's quite unusual to use the position of the sprite to determine the current frame/image. A time based approach would be more natural. I'll see if I can find an example.

Comment: Here's a good [example](https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/comments/3uqpu2/what_is_the_best_way_to_animate_sprites/cxh9jbt/).

Comment: I cant up vote because I am too new, but I have accepted it as solved (which I didn't even realize was a thing). As for the time example - I will look into incorporating that. Thank you again from not only me but the many other people who will eventually see and learn from this. I looked through many posts and was still confused, now others will have a clear, easy to follow example.

Answer (score 1):

[@skrx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6220679/skrx) already described all problems I only add that you can use  [pygame.Surface.subsurface](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.subsurface) to create frames.

```
class SpriteSheet(object):

    def __init__(self, file_name):
        self.sprite_sheet = pygame.image.load(file_name).convert_alpha()

    def get_image(self, x, y, width, height):
        return self.sprite_sheet.subsurface((x, y, width, height))
```

Comment: Ah yes, I had actually prepared another example with `subsurface` as well, but forgot to mention it. Then the `SpriteSheet` class had become rather pointless, since it just wrapped `subsurface`, and I just removed it.

Comment: @skrx maybe add example with `subsurface` to make your answer even more useful.